# Communicating with a shared worker in Dart

Tags: dart

I'm trying to communicate with a shared worker from Dart, but I haven't had any success and I've tried everything I can think of.

As a test, I'm just trying to get a basic worker which simply responds with whatever it is sent working.

Starting from the HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="scaffolded-by" content="https://github.com/google/stagehand">
    <title>wtf</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script defer src="main.dart" type="application/dart"></script>
    <script defer src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>

    <!-- <script defer src="test.js"></script> -->
</head>

<body>

  <div id="output"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript worker (worker.js):

```javascript
onconnect = function(e) {
    var port = e.ports[0];

    port.onmessage = function(e) {
        port.postMessage("Worker received message: " + e.data);
    }
}
```

The Dart code (main.dart):

```javascript
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:async';

void main() async {
  var myWorker = new SharedWorker("worker.js");

  myWorker.port.onMessage.listen((msg) {
        print("Worker says: " + msg);
      });

  new Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
        myWorker.port.postMessage("Hello, world");
      });
}
```

The writer does get invoked every second, and I've verified that the shared worker does run (with chrome://inspect).

To narrow the problem down I threw together a JavaScript version of the Dart code (in test.js) which works as expected.  If you comment out the contents of `main()` and uncomment the reference in the HTML to test.js it works.  Contents of test.js:

```javascript
var myWorker = new SharedWorker("worker.js");

myWorker.port.onmessage = function(e) {
    console.log("Worker says: " + e.data);
}

setInterval(function() {
    myWorker.port.postMessage("Hello, world");
}, 1000);
```

However, when using the Dart version nothing is written to the console.  There are no errors at either compile-time or run-time.  It just silently fails.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I'm probably missing something stupid, but I've been stuck on this for longer than I care to admit…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the worker is a `SharedWorker`, you should call the method:

```
myWorker.port.start();
```

just after attach the `onMessage` listener, ([documentation at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/SharedWorker)):

> If the onmessage event is attached using addEventListener, the port is manually started using its start() method

Also, at the listener, the parameter `msg` is a `MessageEvent` and the text can be retrieved by accessing `data` property (same as your JS code):

```
print("Worker says: " + msg.data);
```

Follow the whole code with the changes:

```
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:async';

void main() async {
  var myWorker = new SharedWorker("worker.js");

  myWorker.port.onMessage.listen((msg) {
        print("Worker says: " + msg.data);
  });
  myWorker.port.start(); 

  new Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
        myWorker.port.postMessage("Hello, world");
  });
}
```

<sub>tested with Dart 1.19.1</sub>

Comment: Thanks!  I'm not using addEventListener (hence the equivalent code working in JavaScript), so I thought that was unnecessary.  I guess Dart bindings use addEventListener internally; I'll file a bug to improve the Dart documentation to mention this.

Comment: It was nothing! Yes, you're right. I found [here](https://webdev.dartlang.org/articles/low-level-html/improving-the-dom#events) that Dart is probably using `addEventListener` at the `listen` call. But Dart's documentation really has to have a improvement. :)